# Windows installation can t see lenovo ssd

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, bios, lenovo-laptop

Windows installation and diskpart can t see ssd but it appears in bios. CPU:i3 1115g4.

I tried running drivers , recovery tool from lenovo and secure boot on and off but it s still not visible.Also can t find intel vmd in bios

Laptop model :E15 Gen 2 (Type 20TD, 20TE) Laptop (ThinkPad) - Type 20TE

Comment: Make sure you have Legacy Mode (CSM) disabled or enabled depending if you are using MBR or GPT.  If you are turning Secure Boot on and off then you must use GPT.

Comment: @Ramhound The installer runs fine but it doesn t see the laptop ssd , also i can t acces the ssd using diskpart either. Laptop bios can see the ssd in there

Comment: Has the disk ever been part of a RAID array?

Comment: @RaZzA - "he installer runs fine but it does not see the laptop ssd" - That is because you are for example booting with CSM enabled but the disk is GPT. What you describe is well documented behavior.

Comment: Had similar issue - Windows 10 installer could not see the SSD which was available from BIOS. Ironically, I found the solution with the help of Windows 7 installer - it could not install on this SSD as well, but at least it was able to detect the drive and display information about incorrect partition already existing on disk. Windows 7 installer allowed me to delete this partition and then Windows 10 installer could see the disk and install successfully.

Comment: continuation of previous comment: It occurred that although it was a brand new disk, it had been returned to the shop by some Internet customer who had created a GPT partition on it. GPT partitions work only with UEFI and my old laptop has BIOS only so it could not install Windows on it but it's suprising that Windows 7 installer was able to handle this situation better than Windows 10 which even with SHIFT + F10 and diskpart could not see the drive.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a missing hardware driver issue, where the Windows ISO/USB installer is missing the needed drivers.

If this is stock Lenovo, you should be able to go to their site and download the needed drivers. Normally when I run into this issue, I just download everything onto another USB to just make it easier vs trying one at a time.

Then when installing Windows you should have the option to select drivers to install, then using the other USB select the driver and add it (if there's more than one, try each one until the hard drive shows up).

Comment: Hello! I already tried many drivers from they re website and also from intel , sadly none of them worked

Comment: Well, that's odd if that's the case. Where are you getting this Windows installation image from? Maybe it's a bad image. Or the other option would be that maybe there's something wrong with the hardware even with the BIOs seeing the hardware.

Comment: The image it s from microsoft website using rufus to make bootable usb , also i installed the same image on 3-4 laptops without any problem. Only on this one it s doing this , I found online some ppl saying to disable VMD but i don t even have that option

Comment: The other 3-4 laptops are they the same model? You could also try rebuilding the USB as it could have gone bad. Don't know anything about the Volume Management Device, seems to do something with RAID. But I would think that really that shouldn't affect anything. I would troubleshoot the SSD. See if you can boot off of a LIVE CD running Linux to use Gparted to see if you can access the drive. If I had to guess there's something wrong with that SSD.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably due to the fact that Intel VMD is enabled as reported [here](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht506197-nvme-ssd-pci-device-will-be-invisible-when-intel-vmd-is-enabled-lenovo-thinksystem). There should be an option to disable Intel VMD in the BIOS, as shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41C71-dvv-4), but on my Thinkpad E15 Gen 2 this option is nowhere to be found.

Other laptop brands also suffer from this issue:

- [HP](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-15-f2000-laptop-pc-series/35900344/model/35900346/document/c06983517?docNotFound=true)
- [Asus](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1044458/)

These manufacturers have links where you can download the drivers. This is not the case for Lenovo.